# Detecting Unnecessary Libraries in target_link_libraries

Tags: cmake

I'm working on a C++ project that uses cmake and we're having issues with inflated build times for some targets. After some digging, I found unnecessary libraries are listed in some of the `target_link_libraries`.

In the following example, main depends on A, which depends on B, so when main is compiled, A and B also get built.

```
add_library(A STATIC a.c)
add_library(B STATIC b.c)
target_link_libraries(A B)
add_executable(main main.c)
target_link_libraries(main A)
```

However, A doesn't include any files from B, so it doesn't need to be listed in the `target_link_libraries`. Is there a way to detect that B is unnecessary?

Comment: I guess this will be OS dependent. Linux/windows?

Comment: Whether linking with a library is needed or not is detected by the **linker** after it read content of the object files. But it is **too late** on that stage to drop dependency between library targets.

Comment: I'm on Linux. @Tsyvarev has a good point. I would be satisfied if the unnecessary link dependencies are detected **after** building.

Comment: A library/executable created contains all libraries, needed for its work, that is actually useful links. You may list these libraries using `ldd <executable/library>`. Then you may compare (either manually, or create some script) list of useful links with a list of all links. According to this comparison you may remove unneeded `target_link_libraries` from your `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: That's a good idea, but I think ldd only works on executables or shared objects and it only shows dynamic library dependencies, not static ones.

Comment: CMake can help you with this via [`LINK_WHAT_YOU_USE` (CMake Docs v3.22)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.22/prop_tgt/LINK_WHAT_YOU_USE.html), albeit this only works for shared/module libraries on ELF platforms. With some luck it may be possible to just temporarily change all libraries from `STATIC` to `SHARED` and then see what libraries are unnecessary.